# German Umlauts in US-ASCII encoding

Tags: input-encodings, german

I got a LaTeX project that has been exported (downloaded) from an ShareLaTeX Online installation. Seems that it stored all Tex files as US-ASCII according to what I see on **MacOS** using the following command in the terminal:

> file -I myfile.tex

Which results in:

> myfile.tex: text/x-tex; charset=us-ascii

The original error is:

> myfile.tex:8: Undefined control sequence. ...\numberline {\thechapter }Vortr\UTF{00E4}ge}{\thepage }} l.8 \chapter{Vortr\UTF{00E4}ge}

And the LaTeX source is (where the \ got copied and pasted here as a ¥ symbol). The original file can be [download here](https://ufile.io/0fx57).

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,ngerman,onecolumn]{book}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Vorträge}

\end{document}
```

The question is, can I fix this somehow? I know that UTF-8 is the better choice. But the LaTeX project consists of many files that are all in the US-ASCII encoding.

Comment: Well, LaTeX is right. You say inputenc that your files are utf8 encoded. That has to be changed.

Comment: Changed to which argument instead?

Comment: ascii according to the manual. And make sure to delete auxiliary files.

Comment: Hmm, I tried removing the encoding since the ASCII encoding is the default one. And I tried replacing utf8 by ascii, but still both options didn't work. Maybe I will just re-create all files in UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: Did you try converting it to utf8?

Comment: Yes, that works. But the project consists of more than just one file ;)

Comment: can you edit the question so that the error message is in a code section (indent by four spaces not `>`) the linebreaks in the error message are important but appear to be lost above. I assume the undefined command is `\UTF` (the linebreak in the error message would confirm) re-encoding the input would not define this command (which is not defined by default)

Comment: ASCII is a 7-bit encoding that does not have accented characters, so whatever encoding your file is in, it isn't ASCII.

Comment: If the original file contains Unicode characters (> 7-bit), then it does not make sense to export them in encoding US-ASCII. It is not possible to get the files in the original encoding? Can you post the correct downloaded file? The code is *not* US-ASCII because of `ä`. Please, post error message as code, not quote. The line ends have meaning and tell the undefined command (likely `\UTF`). BTW, the Mac version of `file` knows an option `-I` (uppercase i) or should it be rather the lowercase option `-i`?

Comment: With "Yes, that works." do you mean that converting the file works and solves the issue and your problem is, that there are many files which you'd have to convert? If so, one could use easy shell scripts to automate the conversion.

Comment: a) when I re-saved the file to UTF8, then Latex worked fine. b) it's a download button from ShareLatex, so I can not control the encoding there, but I'm in touch with the ShareLatex guys to figure out the problem. c) I couldn't copy and paste the error message because the TexShop console won't let me copy the message.

Comment: PS: I uploaded the source Tex file and added the link in the post.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I can confirm that `file` has the `-I` option on Mac OS X, equivalent to `--mime`. If I ask for `file -I` on a file with only ASCII characters, I get `text/x-tex; charset=us-ascii`, but as soon as I add `ä`, it becomes `text/x-tex; charset=utf-8` (because the editor is set to save as UTF-8).

Comment: @egreg Thanks, it's lowercase in the Cygwin port of `file`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exported file has replaced the UTF-8 characters by macro calls `\UTF{...}` with the hexadecimal Unicode code point as argument. The macro could be defined in
TeX, but this will not work in all circumstances (verbatim text, ...). Therefore,
the best approach is to write a script/program to convert the macro calls back to the UTF-8 encoded Unicode characters.

Here a simple script `sharelatex_recode.py` for Python 3. It takes the file as argument and updates the file if necessary:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python

import argparse
import re
import sys

if sys.version_info[0:2] < (3, 2):  # tested with 3.6
    print('Python >= 3.2 is required.')
    sys.exit(1)


def main():
    args = parse_command_line()
    convert(args.input_file, args.dry_run)


def parse_command_line():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description=r'Replace TeX macro \UTF{...} calls to UTF-8 characters.',
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        'input_file',
        help='input TeX file',
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        '--dry-run',
        action='store_true',
        help='the file is not updated and written',
    )
    return parser.parse_args()


def convert(file_name, dry_run):
    with open(file_name, 'rb') as handle:
        data = handle.read()

    new_data, replacements = re.subn(
        br'\\UTF\{([0-9A-Fa-f]{4})\}',
        repl,
        data,
    )

    if replacements:
        print('=> Replacements: {}'.format(replacements))
        if not dry_run:
            with open(file_name, 'wb') as handle:
                handle.write(new_data)

            print('=> File written: {}'.format(file_name))
    else:
        print('=> Already uptodate: {}'.format(file_name))


def repl(match):
    code = int(match.group(1), 16)
    char = chr(code)
    utf8_sequence = char.encode('utf8')
    return utf8_sequence


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The problematic line

```
\chapter{Vortr\UTF{00E4}ge}
```

becomes

```
\chapter{Vorträge}
```

It is also possible to convert all `.tex` files recursively, example for `bash`:

```bash
$ find start_directory -name \*.tex -exec python3 sharelatex_recode.py {} \;
```

Unicode characters outside the BMP ([Basic Multilingual Plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane)) are not supported by the script, because I do not know, what the export of ShareLaTeX to US ASCII does in this case.

Comment: Executing the script worked like a charm. But still there are errors. If I remove `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`, then the output will be **VortrÃďge**. If I add the encoding again, then the file won't compile. But looks like a TexShop problem even though it's set to UTF-8 encoding when saving files. But the original file isn't UTF-8. Weird.

Comment: Seemed to be a problem of the auxillery files. Works perfectly now. Thanks for your help.